# get window title from pid

Tags: c#, window, pid, autoit-c#-wrapper

I am looking for a way to get the window title from process id.

I would like to build function the get the pid of specific window and return its window title.

I try to use AutoIt but it didn't work.

Any Idea?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This should be quite simple:

```
Process.GetProcessById(processId).MainWindowTitle;
```

And if you like it as a function as you requested:

```
public string GetWindowTitle(int processId){
  return Process.GetProcessById(processId).MainWindowTitle;
}
```

Comment: Just to save future Googlers from having to look it up, this requires `using System.Diagnostics`.

Answer (score 4):

This has been done many times in AutoIt before, with the option to return all windows belonging to the process, instead of just the main one.

[This post](http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/48621-associating-a-pid-to-a-win-title/page__p__365849#entry365849) provides the standard solution. In case the rot spreads:

```
;0 will return 1 base array; leaving it 1 will return the first visible window it finds
Func _WinGetByPID($iPID, $nArray = 1)
    If IsString($iPID) Then $iPID = ProcessExists($iPID)
    Local $aWList = WinList(), $sHold

    For $iCC = 1 To $aWList[0][0]
        If WinGetProcess($aWList[$iCC][1]) = $iPID And _
            BitAND(WinGetState($aWList[$iCC][1]), 2) = 0 Then
            If $nArray Then Return $aWList[$iCC][0]
            $sHold &= $aWList[$iCC][0] & Chr(1)
        EndIf
    Next

    If $sHold Then Return StringSplit(StringTrimRight($sHold, 1), Chr(1))
    Return SetError(1, 0, 0)
EndFunc
```

Comment: @OndrejSotolar, It was tagged with AutoIt, the OP doesn't even mention C# in the question so you are basing that entirely on the order of the tags. In any case, someone googling "autoit get window from pid" could end up here so what's the issue?

Comment: Exactly what I did, one of the first few results when I googled "autoit process to window"

Comment: The correct language should be C#, with the AutoIt library.